# Help in Differential Equations - find velocity at t seconds...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, physics, mathematical-physics

Hello Everyone I am stuck where I am , 
Would like to know if I'm going the write path, and any hints on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated !!

Question:

A boat carrying 7 people is being towed at $5 \; m/s$. the combined mass is $800 \; Kg$. The rope is     suddenly cast off and immediately the riders begin to row in the direction of motion exerting a force   of $2,400 \; N$. Assuming the resistance force has magnitude $1600|v| + 800v^2$, find the velocity $t$ seconds after the rope was cast off.

Where I left off:

$m=800\;Kg$

$F=ma$

$F=1600v + 800v^2 +2400 $

$ma=1600v + 800v^2 +2400$

$800a=1600v+800v^2+2400$

$800 \left(\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}\right) = 1600v + 800v^2 +2400$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2} = \dfrac{1600}{800}v+ \dfrac{800v^2} {800} + \dfrac{2400}{800}$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2} = 2v+ v^2 +3$

...

Comment: When you wrote $F=1600v+800v^2+2400$ you missed that the friction force and the rowing force are opposed to each other.  Assuming the positive end of the axis is in the direction of motion, the first two terms should be negative.  You also changed from $v$ to $V$ as your variable and lost the $v$ from the left side. Once you fix those, you want to integrate the equation with respect to $t$.

Comment: I think it should be $F = 2400 - 1600 v - 800 v^2$ is drag is opposite of acceleration

Comment: yes jay72, you are correct, i had made a small error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:
$$
a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{F-R}{m}
$$
where: $ F = 2400\; N$, $R= (1600|v|+800 v^2) \; N$ and $m=800\;Kg$.
So you have to solve the equation:
$$
\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-v^2-2v+3
$$ With the inital condition $v_0= 5\; m/s$

Comment: yes, I have reached there,,, so is my progress so far correct?

Comment: No!Your equation has wrong signs! See my edit. You have missing that the resistance is **opposite** to the force exerted from  the riders.

Comment: Thank you Emilio, yes I see where I went wrong..

Comment: well do ! , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expression for acceleration as a function of speed $a(v)$ then the following holds true:

- Time to change velocities from $v_1$ to $v_2$ $$ \Delta t = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{1}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v$$
- Distance traveled during this time $$ \Delta x = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{v}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v$$

So for you with $a(v) = C_1 v + C_2 v^2$ you have

$$ t = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{1}{C_1 v + C_2 v^2}\,{\rm d}v = \frac{1}{C_1} \ln \left(
\frac{v_2 (C_1+C_2 v_1)}{v_1 (C_1+C_2 v_2) } \right)$$

Comment: im kind of lost lol ...

Comment: You lost the $+3$ in $a(v)$ and I showed some corrections to $a(v)$ in my comment

Comment: This is the direct integration (analytic) method. If you want to use numerical methods you just apply $a(v)$ in small time steps $\delta t$ with $$v \rightarrow v + a \delta t$$ and then $$ x \rightarrow x + v \delta t$$

Comment: The would be $a(v) = C_0 + C_1 v + C_2 v^2$ and it makes the direct integration more complex but still solvable. I was going by the _OP_ statement.

Comment: I see, I will try to make an attempt in understanding what you guys wrote, Thank you guys for the help!